# C# Chat Application AppendText causing problems

Tags: c#, multithreading, appendtext

I have written a chat application which is working as desired apart from 1 line of code which is causing me problems.

In my MainForm  I have:

```
        ChatBox cb = new ChatBox(person); 
        this.AddOwnedForm(cb);
        cb.Show();
```

This is displaying my chatbox, The problem is that this can only be used once If I try to append text in my chatbox thread:

```
        if (Ex.Message.Contains("chat ended"))
           {
             entryBox.Enabled = false;
             send.Enabled = false;
            if (displayBox.Enabled == true)
               {
                displayBox.AppendText("The User has left chat" + Environment.NewLine); // <- PROBLEM LINE OF CODE
                displayBox.Enabled = false; 
               }
           }
```

With the appendtext line uncommented that program will open a chat box once and close fine, but will freeze if I try to open another. Without this line of code the application works fine. I believe it may be a problem with the thread not ending correctly or something along those lines.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. If I have explained it poorly just ask and ill try and do a better job.

**EDIT:**

I tried using a delegate but I am still getting the same issue.

```
private void setDisplayBox(RichTextBox db)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired == false)
        {
            db.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
            db.AppendText("The User has left chat" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
        else
        {
        SetDisplayBox setDb = new SetDisplayBox(setDisplayBox);
        this.Invoke(setDb, new object[] { db });
        }
    }
```

This really has me stumped now :/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to set the text in your user thread. `Control.Enabled` will work fine in another thread but you cannot set any value like Text over there. So append the text in your main thread. you can use `displayBox.Invoke` method to achieve this.

Comment: You may be correct. I will try using a delegate to see if that will work.

Comment: I am accepting your answers as you were in fact correct. I was making cross thread calls all over the place and using delegates solved the problems I was experiencing. Thank you for your answer.